# Error adding a constraint on 2 columns, while creating a MySQL table

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm trying to add a constraint on 2 columns in MySQL and I'm getting the following error:

> lError Code: 3813. Column check constraint 'offer_chk_1' references
>   other column.

Is what I'm trying to do possible?

```
create table offer(
  offer_id int UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, 
  buyer_id int UNSIGNED not null, 
  seller_id int UNSIGNED not null check(buyer_id <> seller - id), 
  sell_ID int unsigned not null, 
  offer_date char(10) not null, 
  offering varchar(100) not null, 
  trade_offer boolean default false, 
  purchase_offer boolean default false, 
  primary key(offer_id), 
  foreign key(buyer_id) references customer(account_id) on update cascade on delete cascade, 
  foreign key(seller_id) references customer(account_id) on update cascade on delete cascade, 
  foreign key(sell_id) references sell(sell_id) on update cascade on delete cascade, 
  );
```

Comment: what version of mysql are you on?

Comment: You edited out the check constraint - why? , and does your create now syntax?

Comment: I added the constraint 2 different ways: seller_id int UNSIGNED not null check(buyer_id <> seller-id)                        and  constraint valid_id check(buyer_id <> seller_id)          non works without the check everything is fine. I'm using mysql workbench 8.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is possible but :

**Foreign key referential actions (ON UPDATE, ON DELETE) are prohibited
 on columns used in CHECK constraints. Likewise, CHECK constraints are
 prohibited on columns used in foreign key referential actions.**

that I found here :

> https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-table-check-constraints.html

And the way to do it if there is no FK on the columns:

```
CREATE TABLE parts (
    part_no VARCHAR(18) PRIMARY KEY,
    description VARCHAR(40),
    cost DECIMAL(10,2 ) NOT NULL CHECK (cost >= 0),
    price DECIMAL(10,2) NOT NULL CHECK (price >= 0),
    CONSTRAINT parts_chk_price_gt_cost 
        CHECK(price >= cost)
);
```

That I found here:

> http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-check-constraint/